# Error in SQL syntax when I try a query

Tags: php, mysqli, format

i've a big (and stupid) problem with a simple sql insert to query (mysqli), i've already used this format without errors, but now didn't work..

please help me find the problem..

```
//Get admin form details
$a_user = $_POST["a_user"];
$a_pass = $_POST["a_pass"];
$a_pin = $_POST["a_pin"];

if($a_user == "$admin_username" && $a_pass == "$admin_password" && $a_pin == "$admin_pin"):
    $keygen = md5(microtime().rand());
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO keys (keygen) VALUES ('$keygen')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $mysqli->close;
else:
    header("Location: ?page=admin&error=1");
endif;
```

Here is the error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (keygen) VALUES ('85faa7f618e433819d7e5ca57076377c')' at line 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`keys` is MySQL reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either wrap it in backticks or use another name for it.

```
INSERT INTO `keys`
```

Sidenote:

MD5 is old and considered broken if you're intending on using it for password purposes.

Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: PS. and thanks for CRYPT_BLOWFISH, yes i want to use it for a random token (a timed-password for admin access)

Comment: @MirkoBrombin You're welcome Mirko. It's best to use for password storage. Also the others mentioned.